# is there a problem with passing parameters between nested map functions?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im trying to navigate to a page in reactjs while passing the parameters using useNavigate hook but as soon as i put in the navigation in the anchor tag it is giving me unexpected token error.

```
<a  onClick={() ={
                                                navigate(`/products/${index.categoryname}/${subcat.categoryname}`, {state:{categoryid: subcat.categoryid, parentcategoryid: index.categoryid, showAll: false}});
                                            }}>
```

in case you need the entire loop here it is:

```
{categoryData.map((index, i) => {
                              return (
                                <li key={i}>
                                  <a
                                    className="sub-cat-hover"
                                    target={i}
                                  >
                                    {index.categoryname}
                                  </a>
                                  <div
                                    className="dropdown-menu-content sub-cat-list"
                                    id={`div_${i}`}
                                  >
                                    <h4 className="title">Sub Categories</h4>
                                    <ul className="dropdown-menu-list">
                                      {index.children.map((subcat, j) => {

                                        return (
                                          <li key={j}>
                                            <a  onClick={() ={
                                                navigate(`/products/${index.categoryname}/${subcat.categoryname}`, {state:{categoryid: subcat.categoryid, parentcategoryid: index.categoryid, showAll: false}});
                                            }}>
                                              <i className="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right text-muted">
                                                {subcat.categoryname}
                                              </i>
                                            </a>
                                          </li>
                                        );
                                      })}
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                </li>
                              );
                            })}
```

In my opinion this should work and im very clueless in where i am going wrong any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can always edit your post and fix the indentation. Anyway, `<a  onClick={() ={` should be `<a onClick={() => {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory hoook from react-router-dom

```
const history = useHistory()
const anyfun =  (id) => {
    history.push(`/login/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi but i wont have any history its just a direct link to the given url

Comment: @ShreyasAgarwal it will act same as direct link...try it once